# Convert unit8array to "stream.Readable" or "Buffer" or "string"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, html5-canvas, minio

I am trying to extract image from video frames, then export to s3 storage min.io (https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference.html)

When writing the image to the s3 bucket using putObject, the 3rd argument "content" needs to be buffer / stream.readable / string. However from code 1, I got "content" as unit8array. I looked at this ([Uint8Array to image in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620821/uint8array-to-image-in-javascript)), but seems not working for my case. Any hints are welcome!

**Code 1:**
This is the code to extract image from video:

```
 if (!video) {
            video = document.createElement("video");
            video.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");

            if (cachingEnabled) {
                this.videoAssetFiles[asset.parent.name] = video;
                refresh = true;
            }
        }

        video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
            video.currentTime = asset.timestamp;
        };
        video.onseeked = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            canvas.toBlob(resolve, "image/jpeg", 1.0); // inside which it calls writeBinary
        };
```

**Code 2:** This is the code to write the image to min.io s3 bucket, the arugment content supposed to be stream/buffer.

```
public async writeBinary(blobName: string, content: Buffer) {
    const bucketName = this.options.folderName;

    await minioClient.putObject(bucketName, blobName, content, function(
        err: string,
        etag: string
    ) {
        return console.log(`"${bucketName} ${blobName}: "`, err, etag);
    });
}
```

Error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): third argument should be of type "stream.Readable" or "Buffer" or "string"

```
16 |     secrect?: string;
```

17 | }
18 |

> 19 | export class MinioStorage implements IStorageProvider {
> 20 |     /**
> 21 |      * Storage type
> 22 |      * @returns - StorageType.Cloud

16 |     secrect?: string;
17 | }
18 |

> 19 | export class MinioStorage implements IStorageProvider {
> 20 |     /**
> 21 |      * Storage type
> 22 |      * @returns - StorageType.Cloud

Comment: Ever figure this out?